# Javascript, after disabling a button, need to make it available again. JS not working

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, upload

Language: **Javascript**  (PHP page)

I have **2 buttons** on a page:
-- One is an upload image button (**#upload**),
-- & another is a "save / submit form" button (**.multi-accordion-submit**).

What the .js below does is it disables the submit button (**.multi-accordion-submit**) while files are being uploaded while user uses the other button (**#upload**) & text inside **#upload** says "Uploading...".

After an upload & text goes back to "Upload More" for **#upload**, the **.multi-accordion-submit** button's disabled attribute should now be removed.

But the problem is, it remains **disabled** and unclickable, rendering the submit button (**.multi-accordion-submit**) useless.

I don't know how to fix it, the code below looks fine & should work.

Any guidance and assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

```js
$(function () {
    var btnUpload = $('#upload');
    var status = $('#status');
    var url = $('#upload_path').val();
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: url,
        //Name of the file input box
        name: 'image',
        onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
            $('#upload-error').hide();
            if (!(ext && /^(pdf|ai|psd|bmp|cdr|clk|gif|jpg|jpeg|ppt|pub|doc|docx|pcx|pic|pict|pct|png|ps|tif|tiff|emf|wmf|indd)$/.test(ext))) {
                // check for valid file extension 
                $('#upload-error').show();
                return false;
            }
            btnUpload.text('Uploading...');
            $('.multi-accordion-submit').attr('disabled', true);
        },
        onComplete: function (file, response) {
            if ($('.file-elements').length > 0) {
                if ($('.file-elements:visible').length == 0) {
                    window.location.href = document.location.href;
                } else {
                    btnUpload.text('Upload More');
                    $('.multi-accordion-submit').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            } else {
                btnUpload.text('Upload More');
                $('.multi-accordion-submit').attr('disabled', false);
            }


            //Add uploaded file to list
            if (response === "success") {
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html(file).addClass('upload-files');
            } else {
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('upload-files');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is going down the path that re-enables the button? The inner `if` statement within your `onComplete` handler doesn't re-enable it, only the two `else` paths do... (Also, I'd use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for this unless you have an old version of jQuery.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//try to use
$('.multi-accordion-submit').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
//and
$('.multi-accordion-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute `disabled` is either exists or not (it`s value doesn't taken into account)

To remove disabled state from element you need to remove `disabled` attribute not just change it's value.

```
$('.multi-accordion-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```

**Notes:**
Actually it may be confusing with jQuery because in 1.6+ `prop` and `removeProp` methods was introduced for work with native properties, but to remove disabled state you need to use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and not [`removeProp`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) (once removed native properties cannot be added again)

```
$('.multi-accordion-submit').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Once the page is loaded you shouldn't use the `disabled` _attribute_ at all, you should set the `disabled` _property_ to `true` or `false` as required. In plain JS you'd do `someElementRef.disabled = false`. In jQuery you should use `.prop('disabled',false)` (or `.attr('disabled',false)` in older jQuery). You don't ever need to use jQuery's `removeAttr()` for this.